# Не сохраняет файл с названием на кириллице

Tags: python, gis, arcgis

Не сохраняет файл txt если путь к папке содержит название на кириллице

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "R:\script\ПИТОН\FIND_test_set.py", line 17, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 3-9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

С английскими названиями работает

```
import arcpy

fc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)  #слой/таблица данные в которой нужно проверить
field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) #столбец в котором нужно проверить данные
domain_1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3) #доменные (эталонные) значения
domain_2 = arcpy.da.ListDomains("Database Connections\sde.sde")#база из которой берутся доменные (эталонные) значения
field_1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) #столбец для идентификации строки
Outfile = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4) #куда сохранять итоговый файл
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)

b=set() #множество в нем хранится эталонные значения
a=set() #множество в нем хранится номера строк с неправильными значениями
for domain in domain_2:
      if domain.name == domain_1:
            for val in domain.codedValues.keys():
                  b.add(val)
with open(r'{}{}.txt'.format(Outfile,field), 'w') as f:
     for row in cursor:
           k=row.getValue(field)
           if k not in b:
                 a.add(row.getValue(field_1))
     if len(a)>0:
           f.write ('СТОЛБЕЦ {} ЗАПОЛНЕН НЕ ПО СТАНДАРТУ'.format(field)+'\n')
           for val in a:
                 f.write ('{}'.format(val.encode('ascii', errors='ignore'))+'\n')
     else:
           f.write ('СТОЛБЕЦ {} ЗАПОЛНЕН ПО СТАНДАРТУ'.format(field)+'\n')
```

Outfile - в ней указан путь к папке
field - название файла в который нужно сохранить

Как обойти эту проблему

Comment: `with open(r'{}{}.txt'.format(Outfile,field), 'w') as f:`

Comment: ASCII не содержит кириллических символов

Comment: @insolor ``UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 3-9: ordinal not in range(128)``

Comment: Какая у вас операционная система?

Comment: @insolor windows 10

Comment: Тогда добавьте полный код. И вообще, такое впечатление, что вы не убрали encode, а убрали только `errors='ignore'`. Перекодировку нужно убрать вообще.

Comment: Добавьте полный текст ошибки с трейсбэком

Comment: Добавьте print(Outfile) перед открытием файла и напишите что выведет.

Comment: @insolor ничего не выдаёт

Comment: Так, а  `print(repr(Outfile))`?

Comment: @insolor скорее всего не выдаст ничего тк скрипт прикручен к интерфейсу через который пользователь указывает куда ему сохранять ``GetParameterAsText``Такое ощущение что все данные из интерфейса в скрипт передаются в ``ascii``  и кириллицу в принципе не поддерживают

Comment: Ну ошибку же вы где-то видите? Там же смотрите и вывод print-а.

Comment: @insolor да в окне выводится итог работы скрипта или ошибки и вот как раз в этом окне выводится Traceback и более ничего результат ``print``  он не выводит

Comment: Что за окно? Просто консоль или что-то другое? Выше трейсбэка точно ничего не выводит?

Comment: @insolor выше выводится путь до скрипта и все

Comment: Добавьте скришнот, попробуйте еще выводить в stderr: `import sys` `print(repr(Outfile), file=sys.stderr)`